# Dynamic insert into temp query hangs for hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP(ID,CID,STS,ETL_NBR,T_ID)
    SELECT STG.ID,STG.CID,STG.STS,STG.ETL_NBR,STG.T_ID 
    FROM DBO.A_STAGE STG(NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN DBO.A_PRE PRE(NOLOCK)
    ON PRE.ID=STG.ID AND PRE.CID=STG.CID 
    WHERE PRE.STS = 'D'
    AND STG.ETL_NBR < PRE.ETL_NBR
```

Above query is constructed from Dynamic SQL inside a stored procedure. Tables involved in joins are actually being read through variables.This query hangs for small volume of data as well.

1) If I perform SELECT based on above conditions, The query still results 0 records. For insert it hangs for hours.

2) There are no blockers on this query.

Note: Since this is dynamic query when other tables are passed to variables this query runs smooth. It has issue with specific table only. I did update stats and rebuild index on that table. No use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PRE.CID=STG.CID

This particular join has NULL and Spaces. It is not Unique or PK column. Hence the slowness. I have excluded them in Join by adding PRE.CID IS NOT NULL .

The query now runs fast.

Answer (score 1):

This can be the classic **Parameter Sniffing**, you can read more here: [what-is-parameter-sniffing](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2011/11/06/what-is-parameter-sniffing/)

There's a way to improve performance with such a queries, using the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` in your query

You need to incluide at the end of query
You can also use the `UNKNOWN` for the each variable, like this:

```
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@variable 1UNKNOWN, @variable2 UNKNOWN, ....))
```

You can read more here: [improving-query-performance-with-option-recompile-constant-folding-and-avoiding-parameter-sniffing-issues/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robinlester/2016/08/10/improving-query-performance-with-option-recompile-constant-folding-and-avoiding-parameter-sniffing-issues/)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. RECOMPILE option is already there at stored procedure level. Do you want me to add at query level as well? Secondly, The variables which I am talking about is defined inside stored procedure. They are not getting passed by parameters.